# My character search loops

Tags: c

I'm working on a project to navigate any maze that is scanned from a file. However I'm stuck on my character searching loop: It will search for the 'S' or the 's' character however after that it won't register the location of 'E' or 'e'.

I had added trouble shooting statements where it prints the "state" it is running like a `printf("");` statement but the testing isn't even printed.

I'm Using Xcode on MacOSX.

Here is the maze:

```
############
#...#......#
S.#.#.####.#
###.#....#.#
#....###.#.E
####.#.#.#.#
#..#.#.#.#.#
##.#.#.#.#.#
#........#.#
######.###.#
#......#...#
############
```

There is no spaces between characters.

```
int main()
{
    int i, j;
    char Maze_array[Size][Size];
    int Srow=0, Scol=0;
    int Erow=0, Ecol=0;
    int flag = 0;


    FILE * Maze;
    Maze = fopen( File, "r");

    if (Maze == NULL)
        printf("Erorr in locating file");
    else
    {
        // scans the file into a 2Dimensional array
        for (i = 0; i <= Size - 1; i++)
        {
            for ( j = 0; j <= Size - 1; j++)
            {
                fscanf(Maze, "%c" ,&Maze_array[i][j]);
            }
        }
        // prints the maze scaned from the file A extra step into making sure its the right maze as well
       printf("Here is the scaned Maze: \n");
       for ( i= 0; i <= Size - 1; i++)
        {

            for ( j = 0; j <= Size - 1; j++)
            {
                printf("%c" ,Maze_array[i][j]);
            }
        }

        // Finds the starting "cell"

        printf("\n\nFinding Starting Position");
        for (i = 0; i <= Size -1; ++i)
        {
            if ((Maze_array[0][i] == 'S') || (Maze_array[0][i] == 's'))
            {
                Srow=0;
                Scol=i;
                flag = 1;
            }
            else if ((Maze_array[i][0] == 'S') || (Maze_array[i][0] == 's'))
            {
                Srow=i;
                Scol=0;
                flag = 1;
            }

            else if ((Maze_array[Size-1][i] == 'S') || (Maze_array[Size-1][i] == 's'))
            {
                Srow=Size - 1;
                Scol=i;
                flag = 1;
            }

            else if ((Maze_array[i][Size-1] == 'S') || (Maze_array[i][Size-1] == 's'))
            {
                Srow=i;
                Scol=Size - 1;
                flag = 1;
            }


        }
        printf("\nStarting Location:\n");
        printf("Row:%i Column:%i",Srow, Scol);

        // Finds the ending "cell"
        printf("\n\nFinding Ending Position");
        for (i = 0; i <= Size - 1; ++i)
        {

            if ((Maze_array[0][i] == 'E') || (Maze_array[0][i] == 'e'))
            {
                Erow=0;
                Ecol=i;
                flag = 1;
                printf("Found Ending Location1");
            }
            else if ((Maze_array[i][0] == 'E') || (Maze_array[i][0] == 'e'))
            {
                Erow=i;
                Ecol=0;
                flag = 1;
                printf("Found Ending Location2");

            }
            else if ((Maze_array[i][Size-1] == 'E') || (Maze_array[i][Size-1] == 'e'))
            {
                Erow=i;
                Ecol=Size - 1;
                flag = 1;
                printf("Found Ending Location3");

            }
            else if ((Maze_array[Size-1][i] == 'E') || (Maze_array[Size-1][i] == 'e'))
            {
                Erow=Size - 1;
                Ecol=i;
                flag = 1;
                printf("Found Ending Location4");

            }
        }

        printf("\nEnding Location:\n");
        printf("Row:%i Column:%i",Erow, Ecol);
    }



    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the results I get:

Here is the scanned maze:

```
############
#...#......#
S.#.#.####.#
###.#....#.#
#....###.#.E
####.#.#.#.#
#..#.#.#.#.#
##.#.#.#.#.#
#........#.#
######.###.#
#......#...#
############
```

Finding Starting Position
Starting Location:
Row:2 Column:0

Finding Ending Position
Ending Location:
Row:0 Column:0

Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: This is probably a good time to start learning how to use a debugger.  Step through every line of code, and examine the variables.

Comment: `fscanf(Maze, "%c" ,&Maze_array[i][j]);` Perhaps reading newlines.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I doubt ... that ends... i should had clearify.ed..... Im talking about the "Finding Starting/ Ending" Cell"

Comment: Im also using Xcode on a Max

Comment: Show us maze file and `Size`.

Comment: I would add `printf("\n");` in the printing maze code after the `for j`, in order to visually see the maze and to verify that the `E` is in the first/last row/column, after you parsed the file.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY just did

Comment: Not link, Not image. And `Size` Plz!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY sorry first time doing this

Comment: Obviously it seems that there is inconsistency in the reading of the file and the file.  Because you are still loading newlines, the assumed position and deviation are occurring.  Try `fscanf(Maze, " %c" ,&Maze_array[i][j]);`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY That actually made it worst... now it won't even read for 'S'

Comment: See [DEMO](http://ideone.com/f9e34I) It is assumed that `Size` is `12`. Since it is not shown

Comment: You're printing your maze without any `printf("\n")` and still you see it as a table, which means that the `\n` are inside your maze array.

Comment: Why in God's Green Earth are you using `fscanf` to do *character oriented input*? Why are you using nested `for` loops to drive the read? Why not `int c, row = 0, col = 0;; while ((c = fgetc (Maze)) != EOF) { if (c == 's' || c == 'S') { srow = row; scol = col++; } else if (c == 'e' || c == 'E]) { erow = row; ecol = col++; } else if ( c == '\n' ) { row++; col = 0; } else { col++; } putchar (c); }` (or something similar)

Comment: @Gary, if this is solved, was one of the answers below helpful in solving it? If so, please consider clicking on the adjacent tick icon, so that it turns green. This marks the question as solved, and allocates a few points to your helper to thank them for their effort. Thanks!

Comment: @halfer no its the one from BLUEPIXY in the comment with Demo

Comment: OK, would you add that as a self-answer then, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the input file containing the maze, each line of text is terminated by a newline (`\n`). While reading the maze into `Maze_array`, if the read character is a `\n`, you should ignore it. In your code

```
    for (i = 0; i <= Size - 1; i++)
    {
        for ( j = 0; j <= Size - 1; j++)
        {
            fscanf(Maze, "%c" ,&Maze_array[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

the `\n` are also read into `Maze_array`. Meaning the `\n` would take up some space meant to store the maze itself and as a result the complete maze won’t get stored into the array.

You can do this avoid this:

```
for (i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
    for ( j = 0; j < Size; j++)
    {
        fscanf(Maze, "%c" ,&Maze_array[i][j]);
        if(Maze_array[i][j]=='\n')
        {
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

If you use this way, while printing the scanned array you have to print the newlines manually.
Do this:

```
   printf("Here is the scaned Maze: \n");
   for ( i= 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");  //Add this for newlines
        for ( j = 0; j < Size; j++)
        {
            printf("%c" ,Maze_array[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

The following method you use to search your 2-dimensional array `Maze_array` is wrong.

```
for (i = 0; i <= Size -1; ++i)
{
    if ((Maze_array[0][i] == 'S') || (Maze_array[0][i] == 's'))
    {
        Srow=0;
        Scol=i;
        flag = 1;
    }
    else if ((Maze_array[i][0] == 'S') || (Maze_array[i][0] == 's'))
    {
        Srow=i;
        Scol=0;
        flag = 1;
    }

    else if ((Maze_array[Size-1][i] == 'S') || (Maze_array[Size-1][i] == 's'))
    {
        Srow=Size - 1;
        Scol=i;
        flag = 1;
    }

    else if ((Maze_array[i][Size-1] == 'S') || (Maze_array[i][Size-1] == 's'))
    {
        Srow=i;
        Scol=Size - 1;
        flag = 1;
    }


}
```

Using your method, if value of `Size` (You should’ve included its value in the question) was 4, the positions (1,1), (1,2), (2,1), etc would not be checked to name a few.

I suggest you do something like this:

```
    for(i=0; i<Size; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<Size; ++j)
        {
            if ((Maze_array[i][j] == 'S') || (Maze_array[i][j] == 's'))
            {
                Srow=i;
                Scol=j;
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Use this when searching for ‘E’ as well. You should get the expected result.

In your code the variable `flag`’s value is never used. Perhaps you wish to do something about it later.

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the comment, you are making things more challenging than need be by attempting to use `fscanf`, which has a number of subtle pitfalls for new C programmers, to do *character oriented input*. `fscanf` is most useful for *formatted input*, but even then there are a number of pitfalls for the unwary. Your other valid option is to use *line oriented input* (e.g. `fgets` or POSIX `getline`), and to then parse each line for the needed content.

However, since you are approaching this from a *character oriented* standpoint, match the proper tool from the C-toolbox to the job. Use `getchar` to read from `stdin`, or use `fgetc` to read from an *open file stream* (you can also use `getc`, but it may be implemented as a macro). Then all you care about is testing for `EOF` to end the read loop, otherwise, just handle each character in the file as it is read (accounting for the `'\n'` at the end of each line).

Simply handling it in this fashion is far more efficient than making a separate call to the *variadic* `fscanf` function for each character in the file.

Putting the pieces together, and noting that if you want to save the input into a 2D array, it's up to you, but there isn't any need to determine where `s || S` and `e || E` reside in the input file. (note: the filename to read is provided as the first argument to the program, if no filename is provided, read from `stdin` by default) E.g.,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int c, row = 0, col = 0,      /* c must be type 'int' to test EOF */
        srow = 0, scol = 0, 
        erow = 0, ecol = 0,
        schar = 0, echar = 0;     /* save char 's' || 'S', 'e' || 'E' */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != EOF)         /* read each char in file */
    { 
        if (c == 's' || c == 'S') {         /* handle 's' || 'S' */
            schar = c;
            srow = row; 
            scol = col++; 
        } else if (c == 'e' || c == 'E') {  /* handle 'e' || 'E' */
            echar = c;
            erow = row; 
            ecol = col++; 
        } else if ( c == '\n' ) {           /* handle '\n' */
            row++; 
            col = 0; 
        } else                              /* everything else */
            col++; 

        putchar (c);                        /* output each char */
    }

    if (schar)  /* if 's' || 'S' found */
        printf ("\n%c found at (%2d, %2d)\n", schar, srow, scol);

    if (echar)  /* if 'e' || 'E' found */
        printf ("%c found at (%2d, %2d)\n", echar, erow, ecol);

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/sefile.txt
############
#...#......#
S.#.#.####.#
###.#....#.#
#....###.#.E
####.#.#.#.#
#..#.#.#.#.#
##.#.#.#.#.#
#........#.#
######.###.#
#......#...#
############
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/sechar <dat/sefile.txt
############
#...#......#
S.#.#.####.#
###.#....#.#
#....###.#.E
####.#.#.#.#
#..#.#.#.#.#
##.#.#.#.#.#
#........#.#
######.###.#
#......#...#
############

S found at ( 2,  0)
E found at ( 4, 11)
```

**Note:** the locations are the **zero-based line/col indexes** for the characters found (which would be the equivalent 2D array indexes if each character were read into a 2D array).

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.